# Fast switch between lock screens?

Tags: root-access, lock-screens, security, xposed-framework

I know there is "No Lock Screen", which is a great musthave app that I have been using for months on all the devices I own. My friends/relatives love it too.

My only problem with it it's that I cannot switch to "Swipe" instead of no password. Since I have an LG, I unlock the screen with double tap. But accisental input also happened with my other Android phone.

So it would be cool if I could just rotate between swipe - pin/pass - no lock screens.

Ps: the app "No Lock Screen" works by using Device Administrator privileges. I have checked the 4.4 API and it is only possible to set no pass, or pass.
However I have root and Xposed on all my phones.